Routing issues with PHP, Symfony and XAMPP on local machine
I recently took over a website from another developer. The website was developed in PHP, a language with which I have no experience, although I am familiar with full-stack JavaScript. The code works on the live server, but I'm having issues setting up a local development environment. Initially, I deployed the site using the php -S command, but I encountered 404 errors when trying to access any pages other than index.php, unless I directly navigated to the file (with the .php extension). For example, navigating to localhost:8000/users/ returns index.php (the home page), but navigating to localhost:8000/users.php returns the expected users.php webpage. After reading some threads, I learned that this issue might be due to URL rewriting. So, I'm now trying to use XAMPP with mod_rewrite enabled. However, this has caused another issue: I now get a 404 error on all static files (such as images) and URLs that don't match the exact file path.
.htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Handle errors
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Hide .php extension

# Externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Specific routes
RewriteRule ^trade/(.*)$ find-trade?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^inventory/profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1&inventory=true [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^trades/profile/(.*)$ profile.php?id=$1&trades=true [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^bump/(.*)$ bump.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide any additional info I tried switching from the php web service to XAMPP with mod_rewrite enabled, but that didn't fix the routing issue, but rather added problem with static files not being found

Whats the folder structure like? That will give you some clues as to whether a php framework is used, and if so, which one. This in turn will give you direction on installing the necessary dependencies for your local setup.

Also see what happens when you comment out (or temporarily rename) the htaccess file. In this way you can see where the pages are not being found as opposed to getting the 404.php as well as seeing what happens when the other conditions are disabled. ... Its not a fix but an inspection.

the root directory contains index,php, .htaccess, web components (header.php, 404.php, etc), /api/, /assets/. /framework/, /ipn/, /jobs/, /steamauth/, /uploads/. The framework folder contains app.php, composer.json, loader.php, /vendor/. The /vendor/ directory contains a /symfony/ subdirectory which I know is a php framework, could that be what I'm looking for?

Could be the symfony. What else is in vendor?

I tried renaming .htaccess and didn't notice any difference when running the local web server using apache or the built in web server using php -S. I'm still unable to navigate to other pages unless I add the file extension to the url and don't notice a difference in console output when I do get a 404 error.

/vendor contains the following directories and files: /coinbase, /composer, /firebase, /fisk, /guzzlehttp, /phpmailer, /psr, /ralouphie, /stripe, /symfony, autoload.php

Inspect autoload.php to see what it does. If this leads to another file, then inspect that one (in your text editor). To verify that its symfony.

autoload.php leads to autoload_real.php in /vendor/composer

And... inspect that file too. (By the way: If it turns out to be symfony, edit your question, title, and tags appropriately.) I have no actual knowledge of symfony and will leave it to the pros to come along; so it helps if your question mentions it as that kind of problem.

looks like autoload_real.php leads to /composer/platform_check.php and /composer/autoload_static.php. autoload_static.php leads to ralouphie, guzzlehttp and symfony. the symfony file's it's referencing are just bootstrap.php files and don't look like they're related to routing but I'll change the title of this post anyways. Thanks so much for the help!

This project may be using Symfony libraries, but it isn't using the Symfony framework at all, let alone its routing features. php -S is the PHP builtin web server, which doesn't know anything about Apache configuration files or modules.
